# elastic lifecycle policy is lost when the index rotates

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index template and a lifecycle policy and an index that is created in the following way to have the lifecycle policy attached to it:

```
body = {
            "settings": {
                "index.lifecycle.name": policy_name,
                "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": index_name
            },
            "aliases": {
                index_name: {
                    "is_write_index": True
                }
            }
        }
```

The policy has a hot phase with a rollover based on size or age of the index.

However what I found is that when the index is being rolled over i.e. from `index-name-000001` to `index-name-000002`, the new index has no lifecycle policy attached to it - meaning it will not be rolled over anymore and keep expanding in size! How do I fix it in an automated way?

Comment: You need to create your index via an index template.

Comment: The index is governed by an index template with an index pattern that matches the index name. I'm not sure however what does it mean to create the index via an index template

Comment: "index template", even though a central piece to this kind of setup, wasn't mentioned anywhere in your question which is why I wanted to make sure first. So you should show how your index template looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have any `_index_template` or a `_template`.
I recommend you use [datastream indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-streams.html).
Here is a good example:

#create an ILM policy

```
PUT _ilm/policy/delete_after_30_days
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_age": "30d",
            "max_primary_shard_size": "50gb"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "30d",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#Create a template

```
PUT _index_template/test_index_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["test-*"],
  "data_stream": {},
  "template": {
    "mappings": {},
    "settings": {
      "index.lifecycle.name": "delete_after_30_days"
    }
  }}
```

#Create an index

```
POST test-index/_bulk
{ "create":{ } }
{ "@timestamp": "2099-05-06T16:21:15.000Z", "message": "192.0.2.42 - - [06/May/2099:16:21:15 +0000] \"GET /images/bg.jpg HTTP/1.0\" 200 24736"}

POST test-index/_rollover
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do have an index template, and your example is not relevant to the question because it deletes the index after 30 days, while I'm wanting the ILM to rollover the index and have it work more than once (i.e. it works on the first rollover but not on the second).

Comment: Also, I'm not interested in data streams.

Comment: I shared it as an example in case it might be useful to you. Anyway...
If you have a template and if this template has the ```index.lifecycle.rollover_alias``` you can rollover. After the rollover, if  ```index.lifecycle.rollover_alias``` is not exist in the new index that means your template is not working as expected. The reason can be other templates that also match your index_pattern. Check the index template  ```order```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates-v1.html#multiple-templates-v1